# Spring Boot Micro-service fails Kerberos Authentication when deployed on Pivotal Cloud Foundry Platform

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, kerberos, hortonworks-data-platform, cloud-foundry

We have developed a Spring Boot Application to query data from Hbase on HDP 2.5. 
The application works fine when we run it on our local windows machines as it is able to find the jaas.conf & krb5.conf file which have been kept under resources folder of the application and we have provided them as system properties in our code as e.g.
**`System.setProperties("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","D:\\host\\workspace\\projectname\\src\\main\\resources\\krb5.conf");`**  

However when we deploy in PCF it is unable to read those file which are set as system properties. 
**Question**
What is the way to set environment variables in PCF ? 
How do we place files in PCF so that they are available to the classpath of an application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an environment variable in your deployment manifest file. 
Here are the [details](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html).

This is assuming your jar file was packaged with `krb5.conf` file.

The other option is to use Config Server. Here is an introduction on [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We were able to figure out from the documentation that we can set environment variables in the manifest file. However in the manifest file under env section we added `JAVA_OPTS:` and provided multiple values in single quotes separated by space as if passing argument to VM from eclipse editor  and it worked.