# Is there a way to externalize kerberos configuration files when using boot and cloud foundry?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kerberos, cloud-foundry

I came across a similar question: [Spring Boot Micro-service fails Kerberos Authentication when deployed on Pivotal Cloud Foundry Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425342/spring-boot-micro-service-fails-kerberos-authentication-when-deployed-on-pivotal). This solution still depends on having the conf/keytab file on the file system or embedded within that application itself.  As this is configuration, it would be ideal if we didn't have to do this.

When using Cloud Foundry (specifically PCF), is there a way to externalize this kerberos configuration completely from your application?

Comment: I don't think you have a lot of choices here.  It's not Spring or Cloud Foundry which requires this, it's the JVM.  If the JVM accepted Kerberos config via system property or env variable, you'd have some other options.  As far as I know it doesn't -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/KerberosReq.html.  Happy to be corrected though.

Comment: Your right. I was hoping that someone would chime in with a creative approach for managing this.  For example, creating this file from the .profile using injected environment variables or something like that.  I am just left feeling that there has got to be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what application you tring to authenticate with kerbero. But I was able to use JAAS to authenticate for KAFKA. And the keytab file path is provided through application properties which can be anywhere on you OS meaning it can be loaded from a PV such as S3 storage that is mounted to you application. Though I am still trying to find out a easy way to upload the keytab file to the storage. See sample code below.

```
  @Bean
  public KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer jaasConfig() throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", krb5_realm);
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", krb5_kdc);

    KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer jaasConfig = new KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer();
    jaasConfig.setControlFlag(KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer.ControlFlag.REQUIRED);
    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("doNotPrompt", jass_config_doNotPrompt);
    options.put("refreshKrb5Config", jass_config_refreshKrb5Config);
    options.put("com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule", jass_config_Krb5LoginModule);
    options.put("useKeyTab", jass_config_useKeyTab);
    options.put("storeKey", jass_config_storeKey);
    options.put("keyTab", jass_config_keyTab);
    options.put("principal", jass_config_principal);
    jaasConfig.setOptions(options);
    return jaasConfig;
  }
```

**jass_config_keyTab** can be equal to "/mnt/keytabstorage/mykeytab.keytab"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a lot of choices here. It's not Spring or Cloud Foundry which requires this, it's the JVM. If the JVM accepted Kerberos config via system property or env variable, you'd have some other options. As far as I know it doesn't -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/KerberosReq.html

Comment: I understand that file is a requirement.  Given that it is a requirement, I was looking for a pattern/process for generating this file based on externalized configuration information.  Another thread suggested obtaining the file from config server.  That option might be limited to a specific configuration of config server (database, git etc.) though.  Still looking for better options.