# Spring boot microservice- Kafka Kerberos - krb5 and jaas config files in PCF - deployment in PCF

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, apache-kafka, kerberos, cloud-foundry

Working on Kafka with Kerberos authentication. For running from eclipse/commandd, setting vm arguments with config files. I want to know how can deploy this in PCF with VM arguments.

I could see some valid answer here. but I need detail answer with sample - [Spring Boot Micro-service fails Kerberos Authentication when deployed on Pivotal Cloud Foundry Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425342/spring-boot-micro-service-fails-kerberos-authentication-when-deployed-on-pivotal?rq=1)

#### Kerberos authentication/authorization for Kafka

there are 3 files that are krb5.conf, _jaas.conf and keytab.conf.

These files are in spring boot classpath or resouces folder. krb5.conf and jaas.conf contains keytab entry.

vm args command:

```
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=./krb5.conf -Djava.security.auth.login.config=./_jaas.conf -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true
```

How I can run in PCF with vm args since conf files are in spring boot app classpath/ resource folder.

Comment: VM arguments work the same in a kubernetes docker container as in the IDE. Perhaps you can share what exactly you currently have and what's not working with it?

Comment: Thanks your reply. 
Kerberos authentication/authorization for Kafka, there are 3 files that are krb5.conf, _jaas.conf and keytab.conf. these files are in spring boot classpath or resouces folder. krb5.conf and jaas.conf contains keytab entry.

vm args command:

-Djava.security.krb5.conf=./krb5.conf -Djava.security.auth.login.config=./_jaas.conf -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true

How I can run in pcf with vm args. since conf files are in spring boot app classpath/ resource folder. 
I wont use kubernetes container in project.

please help me out.

Comment: Thanks for enhance the question. Do you have idea about this? I want to connect with you. How can i connect you.

Comment: I don't know PCF, so I can't really help here